# Angular possible to set default option for object (not list of objects)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple `<select>` dropdown that uses an object, and I would like to set the default option based on the model. For a list of objects I can just use `track by`, but is it possible to populate the default for only an object?

I'm trying to avoid using a list because it adds a layer of complexity elsewhere.

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="status" 
    ng-options="num as name for (num, name) in statuses">
        <option value="">Select One</option>    
    </select>

    <div>Status: {{status}}</div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.statuses = {
    100: 'a',
    200: 'b',
  };

  $scope.status = 200; //should set default option
```

Plunker for reference:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZaIHXz0VyECJBvo9xi1Z?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you just need to set the model a string. Keys (`Object.keys`) of the objects are strings, they aren't numeric (even if you set it as number when iterating through the properties of an object they will be strings, which is what definitely angular must be doing, i.e iterating through the map to set up options).

So change

```
$scope.status = 200;
```

to

```
$scope.status = "200";
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m4N4xNJjWt7b8XwnMQuo?p=preview)**